# Out of stock products not showing (Community 1.8)

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, stock, inventory

I want 'out of stock' products to show in the store, but despite the option `System/Configuration/Inventory/Stock Options/Display Out Of Stock Products` being set to **yes** they still don't show.

Is there another setting that could be overriding this?

Comment: you need to clear your cache and try again

Comment: Done that, several times.

Comment: if the available quantity is set to zero, product may not display in frontend

Comment: Did you rebuild your indexes? Also make sure that the products are associated to the current website.

Comment: This setting refers to visibility catalog and catalog, search.  It doesn't apply to configurable products options if that's what you're going for.

Comment: Stock reindexing will help you.

Answer (score 1):

When the index is built, the following happens:

```
\Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status::prepareCatalogProductIndexSelect
\Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Status::prepareCatalogProductIndexSelect
```

So when you set this to `yes`, all products which are in the index should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set the **Only X left Threshold** to `-1` and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Reindex

- Product Attributes
- Product Prices